# Inputting an array from spark dataframe to postgreSQL through JDBC

Tags: scala, jdbc

so I need to maintain a table with results and input information into it every certain amount of time, as JDBC and spark have no built in option for UPSERT and as I can not allow myself for the table to be vacant while I input the results or for them to be double, I built an UPSERT function of my own. The problem is that I have a WrappedArray of ints in my dataFrame and I can not seem to be able to translate it to a java object that will let me insert it into the PreparedStatement.


The relevant part from my code looks like this:

```
import java.sql._
val st: PreparedStatement = dbc.prepareStatement("""
INSERT INTO """ + table + """ as tb """ + sliced_columns + """
VALUES"""+"(" + "?, " * (columns.size - 1) + "?)"+"""
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE SET """ + column_name + """= CAST (? AS _int4), count_win=?, occurrences=?, "sumOccurrences"=?, win_rate=?  Where tb.id=?;
""")
```

As you can see I tried to write the WrappedArray as a string and then cast it in the SQL code itself, but that feels like a very bad solution.

I made this as the input part, doing different actions depending on which column type it is:

```
for (single_type <- types){
      single_type._2 match {
        case "IntegerType" => st.setInt(counter + 1, x.getInt(counter))
        case "StringType" => st.setString(counter + 1, x.getString(counter))
        case "DoubleType" => st.setDouble(counter + 1, x.getDouble(counter))
        case "LongType" => st.setLong(counter + 1, x.getLong(counter))
        case _ => st.setArray(counter + 1, x.getList(counter).toArray().asInstanceOf[Array])
      }
```

This returns an error that **Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.sql.Array**. I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem eventually was solved by the command createArrayOf

```
st.setArray(counter + 1, conn.createArrayOf("int4", x.getList[Int](4).toArray()))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array` is a type constructor not type:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Row(Seq(1, 2, 3)).getList(0).toArray.asInstanceOf[Array[_]]
```

but `toArray` (with type) should be sufficient

```
Row(Seq(1, 2, 3)).getList[Int](0).toArray
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did try this and what I'm getting is the error:
 found : Array[Object] (in scala) required: Array (in java.sql)